# Can the Adafruit PN532 NFC/RFID be used to read Gen-2 EPC class RFID Tags?

Tags: rfid

I used Mifare Classic cards on a previous project and it worked brilliantly with the RIFD/NFC shield and Arduino Uno. I came across a Gen 2 EPC Class 1 RFID tags. This tags are long range ones. They use an IC chip called Alien Higgs3. I know that the shield itself is not capable of reading from a long range. I would just like to know if the shield is just able to read this type of tag even in close contact.

Is there a UHF RFID Reader that I can use to connect it with the Arduino and read these tags?

Any advice or suggestions are welcome. Thank alot.

RFID Tag Specifications:

Protocol- EPC Class 1 Gen2
Frequency- 860-960 MHz
IC Type (chip)- Alien Higgs3

Answer (score 1):

It can not. The frequencies are different: 13.56MHz vs.868–956 MHz.